# How to count changing values across various columns - Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to look at a specific feature over time for different unique ids, and have it stored in a dataframe in Pandas.

Here is an example with code to replicate:

```
d = {'id': ['adam', 'john'],'t1': ['A', 'A'], 't2': ['A', 'B'], 't3': ['A', 'B'], 't4': ['B', 'A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

     id t1 t2 t3 t4
0  adam  A  A  A  B
1  john  A  B  B  A
```

I would like to count the number of times the t* value changes for a specific id. Example:

John value starts at A and moves to B (one change), then stays at B (no change), then moves to A in t4 (second change), so there were two total changes.

Expected output is as follows:

```
     id t1 t2 t3 t4  toatal_change
0  adam  A  A  A  B              1
1  john  A  B  B  A              2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same idea but using Numpy

```
v = df.filter(regex='^t\d+').values
df.assign(total_change=(v[:, 1:] != v[:, :-1]).sum(1))

     id t1 t2 t3 t4  total_change
0  adam  A  A  A  B             1
1  john  A  B  B  A             2
```

Comment: Now I remember who got me hooked on using `df.assign` everywhere :P

Comment: Yeah, I like it because it follows the functional paradigm of no side effects.  Also, its very convenient when wanting to see results without altering your input.

Comment: I will check this, but would Numpy be faster?

Comment: Likely yes.  But I wouldn't judge solely based on speed.  If efficiency is a factor, we typically state that in the question.  If your data is of reasonable size, it will not matter and you should pick the one that makes the most sense for your purpose.

Comment: @EntryLevelR I added timings, numpy is indeed faster here.

Answer (score 5):

```
s = df[df.columns[1:]]
df.assign(total_change=s.ne(s.shift(axis=1).bfill(1)).sum(1))
```

Output:

```
     id t1 t2 t3 t4  total_change
0  adam  A  A  A  B             1
1  john  A  B  B  A             2
```

This will be slower than it's `numpy` equivalent:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)
s = df[df.columns[1:]]
v = df.filter(regex='^t\d+').values

%%timeit
df.assign(total_change=s.ne(s.shift(axis=1).bfill(1)).sum(1))    
21.2 ms ± 256 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
df.assign(total_change=(v[:, 1:] != v[:, :-1]).sum(1))
1.9 ms ± 8.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df.merge((df.set_index('id').shift(1,axis=1).bfill(1) != df.set_index('id')).sum(1)
            .rename('total_change')
            .to_frame(), 
          left_on='id', 
          right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
     id t1 t2 t3 t4  total_change
0  adam  A  A  A  B             1
1  john  A  B  B  A             2
```

Comment: I'm stealing the `bfill(1)` :)

Answer (score 1):

you could filter the columns and go over all the values in the row and check for change:

```
columns_needed =  [col for col in df.columns.values if col.startswith('t')]
df['toatal_change'] = df[columns_needed].apply(lambda row: sum([1 for val, val2 
                                          in zip(row, row[1:]) if val != val2]),axis=1)
```

which results in:

```
     id t1 t2 t3 t4  toatal_change
0  adam  A  A  A  B              1
1  john  A  B  B  A              2
```

the `lambda` expression in `apply` is equivalent to:

```
def check_chage(row):
    is_eq_next_val = [1 for val, val2 in zip(row, row[1:]) if val != val2]
    return sum(is_eq_next_val)
```